# magit: how to display more visible (desktop) notifications ? (How to get the return code ?)

Tags: magit

**update**: WIP here: https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/magit-notify working but lacks configuration.

I'd like more visible magit notifications: often I want to push some commits but there is an error (a protected branch, I must pull upstream changes,…) and:

- the confirmation or error message is not very visible in the echo area,
- it can appear not immediatly, depending on the project and on the network, in which case I may have exited the magit buffer,
- I'd like immediate visible feedback (green/red),
- I'd like to see more quiclkly what the cause is (currently we must go to magit's log buffer)

so I don't see the error easily and this can lead to a situation where I think mistakenly that I have pushed my changes.

Can we already do something about that ?

[desktop notifications](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Desktop-Notifications.html) (built-in) might be nice (other ideas?) (however I don't see them when Emacs is full-screen) and its api is straightforward:

```
(require 'notifications)
(notifications-notify :title "push succeeded" :body "push to gitlab.com/name/project, branch foo etc")
```

so, speaking about implementation: how do we get the return code, what would be the function to advise ? `magit-process-finish` seems of interest because it seems to check the return code and the explanations. What can we do with that, any implementation tips ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by wrapping `magit-process-finish`. It returns the exit code and stores the error message in the variable `magit-this-error`.

Comment: wrapping with `defadvice` ? I'm not familiar with it yet but I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: I'm experimenting here: https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/magit-notify it lacks some features (filtering of events) and the magit-this-error isn't very explicit ("git failed" instead of "Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes") but it's working and it was easy (one defadvice, less than 10 lines).

Comment: Usually you should get the last error message that Magit was able to identify as such. See `magit-process-finish`'s use of `magit-process-error-message-re`.